# Is there a variational problem that can provide the following class of variational derivative?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, statistics, calculus-of-variations, numerical-optimization

Suppose I have the variational problem

$$
E(y) = \frac{1}{2}\int_{a}^{b} y^2 + \alpha y'^2dx
$$

Variational derivative will provide

$$
\frac{\delta E}{ \delta y} = y -\alpha y'',
$$

Is there a variational problem known in literature that can give me something like as a variational derivative the following

$$
\frac{\delta E}{\delta y} = \left(1-\alpha( y\right)) y - \alpha(y)y''
$$

?

The reason is the following, if I write down a gradient descent I can get something like

$$
\partial_t y = - (1 - \alpha(y))y + \alpha(y)y''
$$

And what I want to describe with $\alpha = \alpha(y) \in [0,1]$ is some measure of some feature of $y$, and I want the update to weight more one term of the gradient rather than the other, based on such function.

Is there anything like this known in literature?
The closest think I could come up with was the EM algorithm, but it doesn't seem to me there's a variational framework for this.

More specifically $\alpha(y)$ could be a sigmoid or some gaussian depending on $y$.

Comment: Can you make your title a bit more descriptive regarding the contents of the question?

Comment: @Clayton I've changed the title

Comment: I return back to my earlier remark, if $a(y)$ is a function of $y$ then $\frac{\delta E}{\delta y} = y -  \frac{1}{2} a'(y) (y')^2   - a(y)y'' $ which differs from your first line.

Comment: @frogeyedpeas I don't think I was clear, If you have $$ \frac{1}{2}\int_{a}^{b} y^2 + \alpha y'^2dx$$ then you get as variational derivative $$\frac{\delta E}{\delta y} = y - \alpha y''$$, therefore you can get as gradient descent $$\partial_t y = - y + \alpha y''$$. My question is if there's any variational problem that can give me something like $$\partial_t y = -(1-\alpha(y))y + \alpha(y)y''$$, assume $\alpha$ is not a constant function, or any other case that can be classified as trivial. I have no clue what you did with your line.

Comment: You can consider my question more like *what's the integral w.r.t. y*.

Comment: To be absolutely clear, is that first $\alpha$ a function of $y$ in $\frac{1}{2} \int_a^b y^2 + a(y')^2 dx$? Since letting $E = \frac{1}{2} (y^2 + a(y) (y')^2)$ then yields $\frac{\partial E}{\partial y} = y + \frac{1}{2} a'(y) (y')^2$ , $\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial E}{\partial y'} = a'(y) (y')^2 + a(y) y'' $. recalling $\frac{\delta E}{\delta y} = \frac{\partial E}{\partial y} - \frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial E}{\partial y'}$ yields $y - \frac{1}{2} a'(y) (y')^2 - a(y) y''$ which differs from what you have written

Comment: Yes, it is a function of $y$, but you should start the other way around (not from the integral but from the process I gave.